# Como armazenar notificações visando desempenho?

Tags: javascript, sql, desempenho, nosql, escalabilidade

Pensando em um sistema que a princípio é pequeno e há uma possibilidade de um grande crescimento no fluxo, qual seria a forma mais inteligente/adequada de armazenar notificações (a la facebook)? Em .txt (não me espanquem..), SQL, NoSQL.. Pensando principalmente no desempenho da aplicação.
Acredito que não interfira, mas a modo de esclarecer, usaria Js no front e no back (ReactJS e NodeJS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que você está preocupado em escalar sua aplicação no futuro, se houver o crescimento esperado.

A decisão nesta arquitetura deve ser pensada em relação à maturidade do projeto em si e crescimento de utilização. Você deve analisar se a implementação de um padrão mais robusto inicialmente é viável para o negócio - o time para entrega de um novo produto é primordial.

Conforme te disse, cada estratégia adotada tem um custo relacionado.
Você pode utilizar NoSql com chave/valor para ter um ótimo desempenho, mas terá que pagar por isso.

Com SQL (acredito que seu projeto deve ser baseado nele), você tem um custo mínimo agora e se houver escala, utilizando padrões de projeto, pode virar a chave facilmente para outro modelo mais otimizado.

Hoje, temos produtos variados, com performances variadas (Redis, Mongo, Cosmos, etc), cada solução NoSql tem ainda uma escolha de modelo a utilizar.

Se tem orçamento e não quer economizar, um padrão chave/valor pode ser ótimo para isso. Mas se o projeto é um MVP e vai fazer uma prova de mercado, reutilize os recursos disponíveis, mas preparando seu backend para mudança se houver uma escala rápida.

Não esqueça que em um projeto que terá alta disponibilidade, você não necessita somente da tecnologia de armazenamento para escalar. Os padrões de projeto são essenciais para esta tarefa.